# "Application Loader" could not choose .app file adobe air

Tags: ios, air, application-loader

I am tring to load ios app app that I have made with adobe air but I am unable to chose the .app file 
when I am trying to choose the file it grayout 
what could be the problem. I follow the instruction from that link:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/app_store_guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a zipped app file. That's all.